# Form data to PHP through AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Used this script many times to pass 1 or 2 values to a PHP file, works fantastic. Using it now to pass 7 values and only the first 2 get through.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form#send_note").submit(function() {
var to_user = $('#to_user').attr('value');
var from_user = $('#from_user').attr('value');
var defaultpic_from  = $('#defaultpic_from').attr('value');
var defaultpic_to = $('#defaultpic_to').attr('value');
var your_username = $('#your_username').attr('value');
var message_title = $('#message_title').attr('value');
var message_contents = $('#message_contents').attr('value');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../inbox/send_note.php",
        data: "to_user="+ to_user +"&amp; from_user="+ from_user + "&amp; defaultpic_from="+ defaultpic_from + "&amp; defaultpic_to="+ defaultpic_to + "&amp; your_username="+ your_username + "&amp; message_title="+ message_title + "&amp; message_contents=" + message_contents,
        success: function(){
            $('form#send_note').hide(function(){$('div.success2').fadeIn();});

        }
    });
return false;
});
});
```

I have double checked all of the names, all is in order it's just the values after from_user (defaultpic_from) and so on won't go through.
I believe it's the way I have the "data:" listed. I am a complete newbie when it comes to javascript so any advice on the properway to get these through would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet the value of your default pic is terminating the query string. You can wrap your vars like this to ensure they are properly escaped:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#send_note").submit(function() {
    var to_user = encodeURIComponent($('#to_user').attr('value'));
    var from_user = encodeURIComponent($('#from_user').attr('value'));
    var defaultpic_from  = encodeURIComponent($('#defaultpic_from').attr('value'));
    var defaultpic_to = encodeURIComponent($('#defaultpic_to').attr('value'));
    var your_username = encodeURIComponent($('#your_username').attr('value'));
    var message_title = encodeURIComponent($('#message_title').attr('value'));
    var message_contents = encodeURIComponent($('#message_contents').attr('value'));
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../inbox/send_note.php",
            data: {to_user:to_user, from_user:from_user, defaultpic_from: defaultpic_from, defaultpic_to:defaultpic_to, your_username:your_username, message_title:message_title, message_contents:message_contents},
            success: function(){
                $('form#send_note').hide(function(){$('div.success2').fadeIn();});

            }
        });
    return false;
    });
    });
```

You will need to urldecode the post vars in php but that should do it.

Comment: also, the scientist is right about .val(). While your method will work, it is more proper to the library to use the intended function. And if this still fails, try changing all those &amp; to just & with no white space between vars.

Comment: DARN same thing. in my PHP file i have the _POST variable going through this function, should I remove it or add a different function now that we added the urldecode?
    $to_user = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['to_user']));

Comment: try checking the answer again. I changed it to use object type post vars instead of query string. This method lets jquery compose the query string itself.

Comment: SOO close, it's going through it just has the %20 between each space. But it's working! I'm going to see if I can explode it with php and dump those!

Comment: don't explode. $to_user = htmlspecialchars(trim(urldecode($_POST['to_user'])));

Comment: HEYY YOOOO that worked!! Thank you very freakn much sir! Have a wonderful weekend!

Comment: you should have to do all that.  just use NVP's (but without the &amp;'s like I said), and then POST will be as simple as $user = $_POST['to_user']

Comment: Reading about NVP's now. Thank you scientist!

Answer (score 1):

1) you know with jquery you can just do this, right?

```
var defaultpic_from  = $('#defaultpic_from').val();
```

2) also, you don't need to turn the & into an entity, but as mentioned, you should be using encodeURIComponent in the values

3) have you verified all the variables actually have values before the ajax request gets made?  what happens when you look in POST?  Are you getting the members in POST, but no values?  or no keys and no values?

4) Try using Chrome's Network tab in the developers tools to examine the request and response

here is an example I am using now, where params is nvp string and sync is true

```
var callService = function(sync, params, successCB, errorCB){
  console.log('ENTER callService');
  $.ajax({
    type      : 'POST',
    url       : 'required/core/Service.php',
    async     :  sync,
    data      :  params,
    dataType  :  'json',
    success   :  function(data){
      console.log('ENTER POST SUCCESS');
      successCB(data);
    },
    error     :  function(){
      console.log('ENTER POST ERROR');
      errorCB();
    }
  });
};
```

what would be really helpful if you could go into the request and response headers and show them to us.  you could have PHP echo

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

to make it easier to get the response

Comment: Unfortunatley I know very little of javascript, just a very basic understanding of it. I passed the values through the php without jquery and it echoed through correctly. I'm going to play around with this encodeURIComponent function and see what I can do. Thank you so much for responding!

Comment: and by respoonse, I mean easier to debug say in Chrome's network tab

Comment: I've had chrome for some time and never took notice to the network tab. This makes life easier. Thank you sir. Well the data is getting sent. Also when i by pass ajax and go right into the php file, the values go through fine.

Comment: when you say go right to the page, you mean using the url and query string in the browser?  That wouldn't work if you are using $_POST.  Are you using REQUEST?

Comment: also, suggested echo out just POST to confirm that everything is being correctly received by PHP, unless that is what you mean by the data getting sent

Comment: Yeah the data was getting sent, it was just the url getting messed up with the stupid way I did the ampersand, Kai re wrote it and it did the trick. Thank you for taking the time to help me out sir. Have a wonderful weekend.